# Is it right to say "Is John lie?"

Tags: grammaticality, modal-verbs

So is it right to say "Is John lie?"?
If yes, why not "Does John lie?" or "Is John lying?". Sorry if it sounds stupid, but I'm a bit confused.

Comment: Is there something that gave you the impression that the first is ok?

Comment: Why the downvotes?  Why close the question?  It's perfectly clear, specific, complete, narrow, non-rhetorical (better word for that?) and it can be answered in its current form.

Comment: You could improve this question by explaining why you think "is John lie?" would be grammatical or telling us where you saw it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Is John lie" may be acceptable in some dialect. I suspect it may be in Jamaican patois, due to the words "is not lie" in the Toots and the Maytails song "Monkey Man".

However it is not what a speaker or writer of standard English would use.

Comment: I just heard this phrase in some video. But why you downvote the question? It's disgusting...

Comment: @lxhgy--you don't know that slim himself down voted. Down votes are not disgusting; they are tokens of question quality.